# Make Jquery remember attr() and data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

A table loads its entries from mysql. When a user clicks button it creates a new table row acting as a drop down menu with options. User can select which option they want and it adds their selection to the cart and changes the image to "mp32.png", "wav2.png", or "track2.png" depending on which option they choose, If they hit the mp3, wav, or track button again it will change the image back to its original state and remove the item. When the drop down button is hit again it will close the drop down menu by removing the table row. But if the user re-hits the drop down button to show the options again it resets the images to original state and forgets they were added to cart. The desired goal is to make it so once an item is selected its attr() and data() are remembered somewhere even if the table row is removed, if the table row is created again it will still show "mp32.png", "wav2.png", "track2.png" and remember the data. Here is what I have so far:

**PHP Table:**

```
<?php
while($sound=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    echo "<tr class='adder'>";
    echo "<td width='40' class='player'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='beats/".$sound['downloadlink']."' class='sm2_button'>Play/</a></td>";
    echo '<td width="250" class="name">'.$sound['name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="red date">'.$sound['date'].'</span></td>';
    echo "<td width='88' class='bpm'>".$sound['bpm']." B.P.M.</td>";
    echo "<td width='72' class='length'>".$sound['length']."</td>";
    echo "<td width='275' class='keywords'>".$sound['keywords']."</td>";
    echo "<td width='96' class='buy'><img class='button' src='buy.png' data-link='".$sound["downloadlink"]."' data-wavlink='".$sound["wavlink"]."' data-tracklink='".$sound["tracklink"]."'/>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).parents('tr.adder');
    var hasNextRow = thisRow.next('tr.added').length;
    if (hasNextRow) {
        thisRow.next('tr.added').remove();
    } else {
        $(this).parents('tr.adder').after(
            '<tr class="added"><td height="100" colspan="2" ><img class="mp3buy" data-product-id="'
            + $(this).data('link')
            + '" src="mp31.png"/></td><td height="100" colspan="2" ><img class="wavbuy" data-product-id="'
            + $(this).data('wavlink')
            + '" src="wav1.png"/></td><td height="100" colspan="2" ><img class="trackbuy" data-product-id="'
            + $(this).data('tracklink')
            + '" src="track1.png"/></td></tr>'
        );
    }
});

$('#mytable').on('click', ".mp3buy", function () {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');
    simpleCart.add({
        name     : $(this).data("product-id"),
        price    : .99,
        quantity : (flag ? -1 : 1)
    });
    $(this).attr("src", flag ? "mp31.png" : "mp32.png");
    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
$('#mytable').on('click', ".wavbuy", function () {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');
    simpleCart.add({
        name     : $(this).data("product-id"),
        price    : 1.99,
        quantity : (flag ? -1 : 1)
    });
    $(this).attr("src", flag ? "wav1.png" : "wav2.png");
    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
$('#mytable').on('click', ".trackbuy", function () {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');
    simpleCart.add({
        name     : $(this).data("product-id"),
        price    : 4.99,
        quantity : (flag ? -1 : 1)
    });
    $(this).attr("src", flag ? "track1.png" : "track2.png");
    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});

$(".empty").on('click', function(){

    $(".mp3buy").attr("src", "mp31.png");

    $(".mp3buy").removeData();
});

$(".empty").on('click', function(){

    $(".wavbuy").attr("src", "wav1.png");

    $(".wavbuy").removeData();
});

$(".empty").on('click', function(){

    $(".trackbuy").attr("src", "track1.png");

    $(".trackbuy").removeData();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the table rows, why not simply hide them? Then you can preserve the data, but the row will be inaccessible to the user. You can use `$.hide()` or add a class that sets `display: none;` to the element.

Comment: Thanks Man! this helped me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Benjarwar's idea I was able to develop a working solution after the row is created toggle between hidden and show:

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).parents('tr.adder');
    var hasNextRow = thisRow.next('tr.added').length;
    if (hasNextRow) {
        thisRow.next('tr.added').toggle('display', function(i,v){return v=='none' ? 'inline' : 'none' });
    } else {
        $(this).parents('tr.adder').after(
            '<tr class="added"><td height="100" colspan="2" ><img class="mp3buy" data-product-id="'
            + $(this).data('link')
            + '" src="mp31.png"/></td><td height="100" colspan="2" ><img class="wavbuy" data-product-id="'
            + $(this).data('wavlink')
            + '" src="wav1.png"/></td><td height="100" colspan="2" ><img class="trackbuy" data-product-id="'
            + $(this).data('tracklink')
            + '" src="track1.png"/></td></tr>'
        );
    }
});
```

Thanks Man!